# Unknown image in my html page

Tags: html, css

i have unknown image in my page:

this is my url:
[my page link](http://droppicker.com/results_amazon.php/?itemId=282027249751&siteId=0)

unknown image:

[image]

how can i find what causing this element?

Comment: Its not an image, right click and element select it / Inspect

Comment: You must provide more details to enable quick analysis. People should not be required to spend several minutes trying to understand your question. The error should be on finding  solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]That's not a unknown image , it is a unknown character , you have an unknown icon at the `:before` pseudo selector

Comment: can you help me?where is the unknown character?how can i find it?its javascript datatable function

Comment: @aram that could be a missing font file, the content "\f429" is undefined, are you trying to use a icon

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but you miss the `Genericicons` font-family.

Here is a snapshot from you code with a reference to this font-family:

```css
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'Genericons'; 
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/genericons-regular-webfont.eot'); 
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/genericons-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/genericons-regular-webfont.eot') format('truetype'); 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; 
}

.pagination .next:before {
  content: "\f429";
  right: -1px;
  top: -1px;
}

.pagination .prev:before, .pagination .next:before {
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 53px;
  line-height: 52px;
  position: relative;
  width: 53px;
}

.paginate_button:before {
  font-family:'Genericons';
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="walmart-items_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="walmart-items" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/tisivu

You need to check why you don't have the reference to the library (maybe the theme not installed well, or bad copy/paste)

Comment: thanks,but i cant find where is the decalre  font-family:'Genericons',what is the name of css?

Comment: It's not declared . This is the problem. I don't not exactly which library your theme meant to use but seems that it's something similiar to the Genericicons library, so you can use it, until you will figure it out, or just keep it.